# Edit, update, delete data from database thru joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am fairly new too joomla because I was working on a CMS and I was advised by a friend to check out joomla before I do it myself. I have installed it and looked at a few tutorials to get a feel.

What I am attempting to do is, 
Have a gridview which is connected to my database that lets me see all my records and I can delete,edit or insert as stated in the title.
Similar to this structure, be able to see a grid and edit the values or select them and open a new page to edit.

Please advise on how I would be able to get this done or if it is at all possible.

Thank you

(Grid view)

```
Name     Age    Class
Cin      2      1
Sam      3      2
```

Comment: http://glefte.blogspot.com/2014/02/xcrud-data-management-system-php-crud.html
http://fabrikar.com/

Comment: Agree with @Len_D you could use [Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a table from the database is an easy task, you use the JTable class to do it:

docs.joomla.org/JTable/load

api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JTable.html

If you don't know where to start writing your php code, my suggestion is to use my Joomla Module Creator to create and empty module and start coding on it: http://paulera.insomnia247.nl/modcreator

Another option is the Joomla! Component Creator: http://www.component-creator.com . It create pages with tables already binded to the DB, but non-editable.

If you don't want to go deep in coding, look for a suitable extension ready-to-use in the Joomla Extensions Directory. Look for TableJX or JGrid - both paid - or anything else in the DataSource category.